# Why does my header file have identifier error?

Tags: c++, sdl-2

I have a simple game project using SDL2.0 and C++.
I think my code is fine, but when I built it in Visual Studio 2019, there occurs 1 syntax error in a Game_Utils header file which has a function using a Enemy variable as parameter. I tried to find and solve the problem in Enemy header but nothing works.

Can someone explain me why that error appear, please?

My repository: https://github.com/Lazy-NMT/Into-Jungle-backup.git

Game_Utils.h:

```
#ifndef GAME_UTILS_H_
#define GAME_UTILS_H_

#include "Game_Base.h"
#include "Enemy.h"

bool Init();

bool LoadMedia();

void Close();

void LogError(string msg, int error_code = SDL_ERROR);

int UpdateGameTime(int &time,int &speed);

bool AppearanceTime_1(const int& time, const int& enemy_speed);

bool AppearanceTime_2(const int& time, const int& enemy_speed);

bool CheckColission(SDL_Rect* currentClip, Enemy enemy);

#endif // !GAME_UTILS_H_
```

Enemy.h:

```
#ifndef ENEMY_H_
#define ENEMY_H_

#include "Game_Base.h"
#include "LTexture.h"

#define ENEMY_HEIGHT 200

class Enemy
{
public:
    Enemy(int _type = 0);

    Enemy();

    ~Enemy();

    bool LoadFromFile(string path, SDL_Renderer* gRenderer);

    void Move(const int& acceleration);

    void Render(SDL_Renderer* gRenderer);

    int GetType();

    int GetSpeed(const int& acceleration);

    int GetPosX();

    int GetPosY();

    int GetWidth();

    int GetHeight();
private:
    int posX, posY;

    int eWidth, eHeight;

    int type;

    SDL_Texture *EnemyTexture;
};
```

LTexture.h:

```
#ifndef LTEXTURE_H_
#define LTEXTURE_H_

#include "Game_Base.h"
#include "Game_Utils.h"

class LTexture
{
public:
    LTexture();

    ~LTexture();

    void Free();

    bool LoadFromFile(string path, SDL_Renderer *gRenderer);

    void Render(int x, int y, SDL_Renderer* gRenderer, SDL_Rect* clip = nullptr);

    int GetWidth();

    int GetHeight();

private:
    SDL_Texture* mTexture;

    int mWidth;
    int mHeight;
};


#endif // !LTEXTURE_H_
```

[Identifier Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9kAyx.png)

Comment: `Enemy.h` appears to be missing a `#endif` for its header guard.

Comment: Hmm, that looks like just a typo on your part, since it's there in the GitHub repo.  It looks like a dependency issue.  Your `LTexture.h` file that is required by `Enemy.h` includes `Game_Utils.h`, which means those function prototypes are declared before `Enemy` is defined.  You need to rethink how your includes work, and also consider whether to pass `Enemy` by value into `CheckColission`.  If you can pass a reference instead, then you can forward-declare `Enemy` to resolve the problem.

Comment: You have a circular dependency: `Game_Utils.h` -> `Enemy.h` -> `LTexture.h` -> `Game_Utils.h`

Comment: There's certainly no reason that `LTexture.h` needs to include `Game_Base.h` or `Game_Utils.h`. Header files should include only what they need to compile themselves, nothing more.

Comment: Same is true for `Enemy.h` and `Game_Utils.h` only need a forward decalaration of `Enemy` it doesn't need to include the header.

Comment: Thanks for all of you, my project had been saved! Yes, it is a circular dependency error. Just tried to include my header files more carefully and I could solve this problem. Thanks again and my apology for the late respond (and my bad English lol)